# Populate HTML table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all and thanks in advance. I need to learn how to fill a table ussing javascript using the structure below.

```
var contacts = [
    {name:"name1", number:"number1", address:"address1", notes:"note1"},
    {name:"name2", number:"number2", address:"address2", notes:"note2"},
    {name:"name3", number:"number3", address:"address3", notes:"note3"},
    {name:"name4", number:"number4", address:"address4", notes:"note4"},
    {name:"name5", number:"number5", address:"address5", notes:"note5"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
            var wrap= function(value) {
                return "<td>" + value + "</td>";
            };

            $("#tableID tbody").append("<tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th><th>Address</th><th>Notes</th></tr>");
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i += 1) {
                $("#tableID tbody").append("<tr>"+ wrap(contacts[i].name)+ wrap(contacts[i].number)+ wrap(contacts[i].address)+ wrap(contacts[i].notes)+ "</tr>")

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('<table>');

var c, i, l, tr, td;

for (i = 0, l = contacts.length; i < l; i += 1) {
  c = contacts[i];
  tr = $('<tr>');
  tr
    .append($('<td>' + c.name + '</td>'))
    .append($('<td>' + c.number + '</td>'));
  table.append(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<table>

</table>
```

Jquery

```
var output='';
for(var i in contacts)
{
   output+='<tr><td>'+contacts[i].name+'</td><td>'+contacts[i].number+'</td><td>'+contacts[i].address+'</td><td>'+contacts[i].notes+'</td></tr>';
}
$('table').empty().append(output)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TpUCN/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, That's what I needed as it show in the demo, but when I try to put it to play with it on my HTML file is not working

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your HTML file? Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yes I did and is working now, thanks, sorry about the noob mistake